# Electric Field between two parallel plans of opposite charge density

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, gauss-law

So considering two infinite parallel plans of opposite charge density let's say  +σ  for the left plan and -σ for the right plan
Why is the electric field calculated this way :
$$  
 E = σ/2εo + σ/2εo = σ/εo 
$$
I understand that between the plans the vector(E+) will point to the right toward the negatively charged plan. The same goes for vector(E-) that goes toward the negatively charged plan.

What I don't understand is why do we not consider the '-σ' value in the equation?

Comment: More on capacitors and factors of 2: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110480/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the figure below. We can look at the field between (and outside) the plates from the perspective of Gauss’s Law (left drawing), or from the perspective of the contributions of two charged sheets (right drawing). Recall the law states that the total of the electric flux out of a closed surface is equal to the charge enclosed divided by the permittivity.

Looking at the upper cylinder of the left figure, we see that the only charge enclosed is the positive charge on the left plate. This continues to be the case as we extend the cylinder toward the right surface. When the cylinder includes the charge on the right plate the net charge enclosed is zero thus the field is zero outside the plates. You can do the same thing starting from the right plate.

The figure at the right uses the approach of the field contributions of each plate which can be summed up to get the same field as from the Gaussian surface. Note that the direction of the field vectors is always that of the force that a positive charge would experience.

Hope this helps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is nice problem that many a first year physics undergraduate will get wrong. We usually recommend using Gauss's theorem to relate the field to the surface charge density. If you do that, then you find that the field is $\sigma/\epsilon_0$ outside a conductor having surface charge density $\sigma$. That's it. That's the right answer for the capacitor. But then the student notices the other plate and they start adding another contribution .... problems. The way to think about the combination of both plates is to argue that you have two planes of charge and each plane of charge sends out field lines in both directions, $\sigma/2\epsilon_0$ each way. In between the plates, the directions agree and add up to the total field. Everywhere else the contributions from the two planes of opposite charge cancel out. (I am treating large plates and ignoring edge effects as usual).

Comment: So we don't care about the '-' of the density of the negatively charged plan?
I understand how the vectors cancel each other out outside the plans and also understand the direction of the vectors inside and the fact that they would add up. 

What I don't get is why do we ignore the '-' of the negative charge density. It's mostly the mathematics part of it that I don't get here.

Comment: The symbol sigma refers to the charge density. Just like charge, it can be of either sign. When we say "the charge is q" then the value of q might be positive or negative, depending on the circumstance. You can have things like "q = -1 coulomb". Similar statements apply to sigma.

Comment: Then why does is not affect the equation that I mentionned above?
If I considered the sign it would go like this: 
    -Between the plates : 
$$ E = σ/2εo + (-σ/2εo ) = 0 $$
   - Outside of the plates ( it can be left or right) : 
$$ E = σ/2εo - (-σ/2εo ) = σ/εo $$  

Clearly this results doesn't make sense. What Am I missing or not considering?

Comment: Hey electric field intensity is vector quantity so Evector =E1 vector +E2 vector ok if now you take direction of E1 positive then E2 Should also be positive because it is in the same direction as that of E1.